# Google HotelFinder API

Tags: google-api

I would like to find the API that will enable my company to write into the Google HotelFinder API, so that when results appear in HotelFinder, our booking engine can publish a rate under the Hotel brand Website field?  Can anyone help with this info please?
Rgds